# Google Places API - Details Request

Tags: google-places-api

I'm a currently making a website that uses your current location and finds the nearest doctors for you. I'm using the Google Places API for this.

The website succesfully finds the nearest doctors without a problem, but it doesn't display the details yet and I have problems implementing this.

After some research I found more details about the code I think need to implement ([HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?csw=1#place_details)).

I've been doing some research and testing alot of different things out, but I can't find where or how I need to implement this in my code. I'm new to developping so I might be overlooking something obvious.

Thank you for reading!

Here is my code which I use to find the doctors near the user's current location.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    });


var map, placesList;

function initialize(position) {

  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;

  var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: currentLocation,
    zoom: 8
  });

  var request = {
    location: currentLocation,
    radius: 750,
    types: ['doctor']
  };

  placesList = document.getElementById('places');

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status, pagination) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    return;
  } else {
    createMarkers(results);

    if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
      var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');

      moreButton.disabled = false;

      google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(moreButton, 'click',
          function() {
        moreButton.disabled = true;
        pagination.nextPage();
      });
    }
  }
}

function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';

    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little too late, but I had the same question and got an answer. The details of each store is on the marker and I can't figure out to list all the details instead. However this might help you!
[Google Places API- Address and phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965425/google-places-api-address-and-phone-number)