# Google Places API- Address and phone number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a list and map via Google Places. The following displays makers and a list of local stores. Right now it only shows the name of the store. How would I include Address and Phone? Would I add another object specification?

UPDATE: According to this link: [Google Places API - Places detail request undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520808/google-places-api-places-detail-request-undefined)

place.getDetails() should be added. However my script now only shows one market and not details. What is going on?

UPDATE UPDATE:

HTML example here: http://simplecomputerblog.com/searchtest1.html

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
var map, placesList;
var infowindow;
var service; //declare globally


function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(40.062664, -83.069101);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   placesList = document.getElementById('places');
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location
 });

var request = { reference: place.place_id };
service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
 });
 placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details), you can easily get a handle on the `number` and `address` of the place(s) you fetch by doing:

```
  function createMarker(place) {
   var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: place.geometry.location
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name+place.formatted_address+place.formatted_phone_number);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
   placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';
 }
```

Again from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows):

> The content of the InfoWindow may contain a string of text, a snippet
>   of HTML, or a DOM element. To set the content, either specify it
>   within the InfoWindowOptions or call setContent() on the InfoWindow
>   explicitly.

**EDIT**-
As rightly pointed out [results](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?csw=1#place_search_responses) for `nearbySearch` don't return `formatted_address` and `formatted_phone_number` in the `result` object and for that you'll  have to make another `getdetails` request like you have already incorporated in your code. It might look something like (untested):

```
 function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location
 });

var request = { placeId: place.place_id };
service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
 });
 placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';
}
```

It's important that `service` is available to the scope of the functions you use it in. So declare it outside all the functions and initialize it appropriately like so:

```
var service; //declare globally
function intialize(){
   ...
   service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map); //initialize here

   ...
}
```

So you can format that content string accordingly and populate the infowindow. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: One problem. The phone number and so on is coming up undefined. Funny thing I was looking at a post about that. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520808/google-places-api-places-detail-request-undefined  . Trying to implement the code.

Comment: The link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520808/google-places-api-places-detail-request-undefined

Comment: Updated. Have a new problem.

Comment: @BenjaminJones, I have updated my answer to include two things. First try using `place_id` instead of `reference` to get the details of the place as use of `reference` is deprecated now and might cause unwanted behavior. Second, just make sure, the `service` object is available inside the `createMarker()` function. You might have to define it globally. I have incorporated the mentioned changes in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm followed what you said, now a blank page. I have updated my post. I haven't gotten a chance to dig into this yet. I will. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added another update! Figured out the blank page. I was able to add your suggestions successfully, however I can not get any information from the markers. Also if I Initialize service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);, it shows the blank page.

Comment: @BenjaminJones, pardon my ignorance. I completely ovrlooked this typo as I couldn't test this code myself. It should be `var request = { placeId: place.place_id };` instead of var `request = { reference: place.place_id };` as defined earlier. I looked at the test [link](http://simplecomputerblog.com/searchtest1.html) you gave me and it threw an error in the console suggesting `Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId.` which prompted me to check for typos.

Comment: Thank you so much that works! Can you update your code for others to reflect var request = { placeId: place.place_id }; ?

Comment: @BenjaminJones, I did that already. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65102/discussion-between-benjamin-jones-and-vivek-pradhan).